# Unsure about the .include method - Need help debugging

Tags: ruby

I am creating a simple Magic-8 Ball program in Ruby. I want to make sure the user asks a question, so I've used the .include method in my conditional statements. I swore I was using it correctly, but I am getting errors when I run the program in the terminal.

I've tried using the .include method in different ways according to what I found on google, but nothing seems to be working.

```
    puts "Please ask the Magic 8 Ball a YES/NO question:"
    question = gets.chomp

    puts "Please enter your name:"
    name = gets.chomp

    magic_8 = rand(6)

    if question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 0
      puts "\nIt is certain, #{name}."
    elsif question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 1
      puts "\nI'm not so sure, #{name}."
    elsif question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 2
      puts "\nI'll have to get back to you on that, #{name}."
    elsif question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 3
      puts "\nIt's not likely, #{name}."
    elsif question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 4
      puts "\nAbsolutely, #{name}!"
    elsif question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 5
      puts "\nDefinitely not, #{name}."
    else
      puts "Please enter a valid YES/NO question, #{name}."
    end
```

I am expecting the program to output the conditional statements randomly as long as the user enters a question containing a "?".

Comment: "...nothing seems to be working." is inadequate. An exception was raised and the error message and line number would pinpoint the problem. I expect the error message was, `TypeError (no implicit conversion of true into String)` and it occurred in the line `if question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 0`. You need to report that information in your question and, more importantly, you need pay close attention to error messages and learn what they mean.

Comment: I am new to this. But thank you.

Comment: "nothing seems to be working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "nothing **seems** to be working"? Does it work or doesn't it work?

Comment: I was able to get some help with this, but I will pay more attention to how I post in future. I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:9:in `include?': no implicit conversion of false into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

The problem is precedence. You can usually get away with not putting parenthesis around method arguments, but not this time.

```
question.include? "?" && magic_8 == 0
```

You're expecting this:

```
question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 0
```

But because `&&` has a very high precedence, Ruby is interpreting this.

```
question.include?("?" && magic_8 == 0)
```

`"?" && magic_8 == 0` is `false` so that's `question.include?(false)` which doesn't make sense.

So you need to be explicit about your parens. `question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 0`.

We can also avoid the problem entirely by noticing that you're checking `question.include?("?")` over and over again. This can be pulled into its own if/else block.

```
if question.include?("?")
  case magic_8
  when 0
    puts "\nIt is certain, #{name}."
  when 1
    puts "\nI'm not so sure, #{name}."
  when 2
    puts "\nI'll have to get back to you on that, #{name}."
  when 3
    puts "\nIt's not likely, #{name}."
  when 4
    puts "\nAbsolutely, #{name}!"
  when 5
    puts "\nDefinitely not, #{name}."
  end
else
  puts "Please enter a valid YES/NO question, #{name}."
end
```

We only need to check if they've asked the question once. Then inside that `if` we can use [case/when](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/), which is like a more convenient if/elsif, to check the 8 ball.

Comment: A detail: one could write (at the end) `magic8_messages = { 0=>"\nIt is certain", 1=>"\nI'm not so sure", ...,  6=>"Please enter a valid YES/NO question" }; puts "#{magic8_messages[magic8]}, #{name}"` (if "Absolutely" can be can be stated with less enthusiasm).

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses for arguments to method calls. You're confusing the interpreter without them.

```
if question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 0
  puts "\nIt is certain, #{name}."
elsif question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 1
  puts "\nI'm not so sure, #{name}."
elsif question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 2
  puts "\nI'll have to get back to you on that, #{name}."
elsif question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 3
  puts "\nIt's not likely, #{name}."
elsif question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 4
  puts "\nAbsolutely, #{name}!"
elsif question.include?("?") && magic_8 == 5
  puts "\nDefinitely not, #{name}."
else
  puts "Please enter a valid YES/NO question, #{name}."
end
```

More [here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-invocation-parentheses).